# Not enough values error message Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, database-schema

i am getting an error message when trying to insert a record, i have double checked all the values are present and data types are consistent. Can someone please help me spot the issue.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE EMP_ID_SEQ
START WITH 300
INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE TABLE STAFF(
EMP_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
EMP_NAME VARCHAR2(20),
EMP_DOB DATE,
EMP_TEL VARCHAR2(20),
EMP_EMAIL VARCHAR2(50),
EMP_ADDR VARCHAR2(100),
EMP_HIREDATE DATE,
EMP_ENDDATE DATE,
EMP_SALARY NUMBER(7,2),
EMP_SUPERVISOR NUMBER,
 JOB_CODE NUMBER,
 BRA_CODE NUMBER);

 CREATE TRIGGER EMP_ID_TRG
BEFORE INSERT ON STAFF
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT EMP_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL
INTO :NEW.EMP_ID
FROM DUAL;
END;
/

INSERT INTO STAFF VALUES ('Jaime Stark',to_date('29/04/1951','dd/mm/YYYY'),'607 4432-1059','Donec.fringilla.Donec@necurnaet.ca','P.O. Box 891, 5837 Enim Avenue',to_date('16/06/2010','dd/mm/YYYY'),NULL,41695,NULL,1,1);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO STAFF VALUES (null,'Jaime Stark',to_date('29/04/1951','dd/mm/YYYY'),'607 4432-1059','Donec.fringilla.Donec@necurnaet.ca','P.O. Box 891, 5837 Enim Avenue',to_date('16/06/2010','dd/mm/YYYY'),NULL,41695,NULL,1,1);
```

or

```
INSERT INTO STAFF (EMP_NAME,EMP_DOB,EMP_TEL,EMP_EMAIL,EMP_ADDR,EMP_HIREDATE,EMP_ENDDATE,EMP_SALARY,EMP_SUPERVISOR,JOB_CODE,BRA_CODE)
VALUES ('Jaime Stark',to_date('29/04/1951','dd/mm/YYYY'),'607 4432-1059','Donec.fringilla.Donec@necurnaet.ca','P.O. Box 891, 5837 Enim Avenue',to_date('16/06/2010','dd/mm/YYYY'),NULL,41695,NULL,1,1);
```

Comment: I get error saying cannot insert null, maybe there is something wrong with my sequence? or trigger not setting the right primary key for emp_id

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos, it sounds like your trigger may not be firing for some reason.  I used your creation statements exactly as shown above, and both of turbanoff's insert statements worked for me.  So maybe you've done something while troubleshooting like disabling or dropping the trigger.  If possible, drop and recreate the table and trigger then re-try the inserts from this answer.